# I am updating and modifying already existing Shiny code to suit my project but it creates an Error in if: argument is of length zero

Tags: r, shiny

[image]The code I updated creates an "Error in if:argument is of length zero. I have 2 photos attached of what it should look like (the original code) and what I am getting (updated code). All I have done is substituted the MSFD Descriptors for Ecosystem services. I have modified all codes to suit this action but I keep getting the error. Below is a copy of the error. Thank you for any help.

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6999
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
98: graph_obj [C:/Users/caitr/OneDrive/Desktop/R/Shiny.R#289]
96: htmlwidgets::shinyRenderWidget
95: func
82: renderFunc
81: output$horrendogram
1: runApp

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to help looking only at the error message. Is it possible to share relevant code and data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Typically this error means that there's an if statement in which you are referring to a column that doesn't exist but it would be a lot easier if we can take a look at a bit of the code and the table that you substituted